# HTML5 video backgorund on WordPress website not working on Safari browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress

​Recently i developed a site using WordPress theme. Here is site url.

https://hbutterfly.com/

I have a HTML5 video background on Hero section. Video background works on Firefox and Chrome. But it's doesn't work on Safari browser.​ Kindly check below code.

```
<div class="nectar-video-wrap position-loaded" data-bg-alignment="" style="opacity: 1; width: 1366px; height: 100%;">
  <div class="nectar-video-inner">
        <video class="nectar-video-bg" width="1800" height="700" preload="auto" loop="" autoplay="" muted="" playsinline="" style="visibility: visible;width: 1366px;height: 769px;opacity: 1;">
           <source src="https://hbutterfly.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/HB-updated-website-video_720p.webm" type="video/webm">
           <source src="https://hbutterfly.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/HB-updated-website-video_720p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the console on Safari, you'll see this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   https://hbutterfly.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/HB-updated-website-video_720p.mp4

because your MP4 file doesn't exist.

The reason your video works on some browsers is that both Chrome and Firefox support the WebM format. Safari doesn't, so it has to fallback to the MP4, which doesn't exist.

So, you just have to upload both video formats.